# What API do I use with the permissions my Teams app received in App Studio?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, azure-ad-graph-api

I am developing an app in Microsoft Teams using the App Studio. Towards the end of the proccess, in the section *Domains and Permissions*, you are allowed to give resource-specific consent permissions such as `File.Read.Group`. I was wondering where I would use these permissions (Microsoft Graph, Azure AD Graph, ...) to programmatically access an API. As a side question, does anybody know which permission allows the app to manage group members?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good read on that permissions settings page, those consent permissions are not actually a part of azure ad app registrations as of this articles writing. so that means while they are sort of graph permissions, you would use them against the graph api. They are for specific teams based resource specific permissions.
https://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2020/01/microsoft-teams-has-a-new-more-granular-and-resource-specific-permissions-model-for-apps-what-is-resource-specific-consent-rsc-and-how-do-i-use-it/

the official documentation on the matter: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/rsc/resource-specific-consent

as per the microsoft link i don't see a resource specific permission to "edit" groups members.